# "they" vs. "ones"

Tags: pronouns

This is an excerpt from an NBC news article. Does "numbers" refer to the latest year's English scores and "they" refer to the previous 30 years' English ones? If it is the case, should "they" replaced with "ones" because "they" does not refer to the latest year's English scores? Like "And in English, numbers dropped more than ones have in 30 years." [This is the news](https://archive.org/details/KNTV_20220902_013000_NBC_Nightly_News_With_Lester_Holt/start/811/end/871?q=Here%27s%20Stephanie%20Gosk.%20After%20two%20and%20a%20half%20years%20of%20COVID%20disruptions%2C%20it%20is%20time%20to%20take%20stock%20of%20the%20nation%27s%20schools%2C%20and%20the%20picture%20isn%27t%20good.).

> We’re back now with the alarming but for many parents not surprising
> new data on just how pandemic schooling has affected students. Here's
> Stephanie Gosk. After two and a half years of COVID disruptions, it is
> time to take stock of the nation's schools, and the picture isn't
> good.
>
> “We had interrupted school. We’d have school closures. Kids missed
> school for a time ‘cause they got COVID.” The National
> Assessment of Educational Progress tested nearly 15,000 9-year-olds
> from across the country, something the organization has done every
> year since the '70s.
>
> For the first time ever, third and fourth graders lost ground in math.
> And in English, **numbers** dropped more than **they** have in 30 years. The
> study highlights the disparities. Higher achievers' scores fell three
> points in math. Lower achievers' dropped ten.

Comment: It's *spoken* text, so it's far from perfect English. For example, ***We had** interrupted school. **We’d have** school closures* is a bizarre combination of tenses that wouldn't normally make it into print. It's impossible to say whether ***numbers*** refers to the number of students taking exams in maths (most likely from the *vocabulary*), or their ***test scores*** (*logically* most likely). But unquestionably, ***they*** refers to the ***numbers*** (whatever they represent).

Comment: ...sorry - I stopped looking at the text after ***...30 years.*** What follows makes it unambiguously clear we're talking about ***scores***. Idiomatically, ***numbers*** is a poor word choice here (which a proofreader would probably change before sending the text to the printers). But there is a tendency to say *the **numbers** don't look good* when *any* unpromising data becomes available.

Comment: "Ones" sounds less natural than "they" to me. "Ones" normally denotes individual items or occasionally encountered things, not aggregate data, and is more commonly used with a qualifier such as "these ones", "the blue ones", etc, whereas you couldn't use "they" with such qualifiers. (It's true that "scores dropped more than they have in 30 years" would be better, but that's nothing to do with ones vs they.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "We had interrupted school."(→We had interrupted school for a time in the past.) 
"We’d have school closures."(→We would have school closures. →We used to have school closures on an irregular basis.)
I don't guess the two sentences are awkward if they are interpreted as the sentences in the parentheses.

Comment: That "verb tense clash" isn't some clever literary device with a deep meaning. Like I said, it's just a trivial "slip of the tongue" in a *spoken* context.

Comment: @StuartF If "scores dropped more than they have in 30 years" means scores dropped more than scores have dropped in 30 years, the former scores are not identical with the latter ones since the former is a different set of scores of a different set of students at a different time compared with the latter, so I guess "they" cannot substitute for the latter. I wonder whether the reporter committed an error, trying to make words shorter.

Comment: The only "oddity" I see is that ***numbers*** is a rather loose usage here, corresponding to ***scores** [specifically, for **English** tests]*. It's irrelevant that every year it's a different set of 9-year-olds taking the tests - what matters is that the tests themselves are "comparable" from year to year, so it's meaningful to compare the scores to see how they change over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"And in English, numbers dropped more than they have in 30 years". means:

"**The numbers in English dropped more [now] than they have [dropped] in 30 years**".

*In speech*, to go on to a new subject, speakers will often use this type of structure: And in [subject], x occurred.

Yes, numbers here means **test scores**. And no, you don't change the words of what an interviewed person says.

Bear in mind that not everything a person says in an interview, will sound like a written, edited text, all clean and shiny,

Comment: In "And in English, numbers dropped more than they have in 30 years," I guess if it means "Numbers in English now dropped more than numbers have dropped in 30 years," the former numbers are not identical with the latter numbers since the former is a different set of scores of a different set of students at a different time compared with the latter, so the latter numbers cannot be replaced with "they", which refers to the former numbers.
The sentence is spoken by the reporter, not an interviewee, so I guess it should be supposed to be rather refined.

Comment: @JiHyunLee In this sentence: And in English, numbers dropped more than they have in 30 years.  There are no "former and latter numbers". There is how the numbers behaved this year compared to the last 30 years. The speech is not ""refined'. It is just standard speech.